# Export all Redirect Maps

Tags: sitecore-client, powershell-extensions

Is there a way to export all redirect maps via a `PowerShell` script or a simple GUI in Sitecore that I am missing?  I want a list of them all - don't care about the formatting as long as I can make sense of it.

I have 3 Redirect Map Groupings and redirects under those.  I simply would like to export everything under Sitecore's main Redirects group.

The setup is as described here - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/map-a-url-redirect.html

Is this possible without a heavy lift, installing something, and/or going one by one copying out the raw values for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example at how you can take a known root ID of "Redirects" and output all of the mappings.

```
$redirectsRootId = "{CE4886A6-0372-42FB-B27E-B1E417A4A2F2}"
$redirectMaps = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:" -ID $redirectsRootId | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -eq "{F4FB6125-F113-4373-8AA2-4648C2C1960E}" }
$records = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach($redirectMap in $redirectMaps) {
    $nameValues = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($redirectMap.UrlMapping)
    foreach($key in $nameValues.AllKeys) {
        $record = [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Old" = $key
            "New" = $nameValues[$key]
        }
        $records.Add($record) > $null
    }
}

$records | Show-ListView
```

[image: Sample Report]

## References

- [NameValueList](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/code-snippets/field-types#edit-namevaluelistfield)

Comment: That generally worked.  When I go to the redirect group parent of the redirects.  So thank you for that, but is there a way to use the grandparent?  The way Sitecore recommends (and our current setup) is in the content editor under the tree of "Setting" > there is a "Redirects" node and under that node are all the redirect groups and under the redirect groups are the redirects. So Settings > Redirects > (a bunch different groups) > the targets.  I can get the id of the grandparent "Redirects", but when I run the script at that level nothing is returned.

Comment: You can add `-Recurse` to the call to `Get-ChildItem` if you use nested folders. You can also do more filtering and add columns if you need to distinguish between which RedirectMap is being shown. So many options!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the PowerShell script way you are looking for. Just a workaround, I used to fetch all the redirect URLs under Redirect Map Groupings.

- Click on the redirect map item and check `raw values` from the view tab.
- Grab the complete string from the field `Mapping between old and new URL paths` and paste this string into the editor (notepad++). You can replace `&` with the new line.
- Now you will have the complete list in format `source URL=target URL`.You can further take this list to excel and split it with `=`

[image]